# PHP Getting file extension returning .file

Tags: php

When i use this function to get the file extension:

```
function getExtension($file){
    $fileName  = $_FILES[$file]['name'];
    $extension = strtolower(pathinfo($fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    return $extension;
```

It just returns **.file** even though the file i submitted in the form was **.pdf** 
Any suggestion to solve this?

Comment: Are you using a framework? The uploaded file may be the name of a temporary file, in /tmp for example. You should `print_r($_POST); print_r($_FILES);` and look at the output first. Is the real filename there somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code will return the uploaded file extension.

```
function getExtension($file)
  {
    $fileName  = $_FILES[$file]['name'];
    $fileArr = explode(".", $fileName);
    return end($fileArr);
  }
```